# Manipulating very large text file and clustering analysis

Tags: c#, python, text, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to work with a (very) large 45gb .txt file that cannot be opened using normal text editors.

Data within each row is separated by a spacing, although there are also spaces within each parameter. For example, 1 row looks somewhat like this:

> University of Cambridge CB2 1TQ 0001234567 2011-01-25 12345 11.12345
>   12.12345 13.12345 14.1234 16.2716)

What I would want to is essentially to clean it up, filter some data, sum up some cells/parameters, append some additional data to each row, and perform clustering analysis (probably with python or C# since I'm starting to pick it up).

Comment: If you use the `vim` editor, it can open very large files easily.

Comment: This data can be parsed easily - so as long as you start from the right.  Once 10 fields have been found, the rest is the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well having it in a database sounds like a good start, rather than trying to do all your data munging from a text file. If you know you can filter the data *right now* then that might make life easier too.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        # Filter
        # If filter passes, add to batch
        # At a batch size n, insert to db and restart batch
```

Now your data is in a database and you can execute arbitrary SQL queries against it in a more performant way, get aggregate stats like sums, and append values. You can extract samples from it for your ML ops or use `fit generator` methods that do queries. I've used the clustering implementations in Python scikit-learn and I enjoyed working with them, but I don't recall there being any out-of-memory implementations. (I can't speak to c# libraries since I haven't used them.)

Python has DB APIs in stdlib like https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Python has ORM with https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Python also has public cloud database SDKs like

> https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html

and

> https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-sql